# How to change the label color of a Primefaces/jqPlot line chart?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jqplot

I have a simple JSF line chart that uses PrimeFaces (via jqPlot)  library:

```
<p:lineChart id="linear"
             value="#{team.chart}" 
             title="Lap Times" 
             xaxisLabel="Lap"
             yaxisLabel="Time (sec)"
             style="height:300px;width:600px" />
```

However, I want to change the title and X/Y label colors of the chart. I can't seem to find the right combination of CSS to make this happen. For example, the following DOES NOT work:

```
.jqplot-xaxis {
     /* skin */
     font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; 
     color: white ! important;
     font-size: 90%;
 }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what I use for the title and X/Y labels of my charts:

```
.jqplot-title{
    color: #eeffdd;
}
.jqplot-xaxis-label{
    color: #eeccaa; 
}
.jqplot-yaxis-label{
    color: #eeccaa;
}
```

The setting of the `.jqplot-xaxis` class works fine it only changes the ticks of the xaxis. you can test it quickly by setting e.g. `font-size: 20px;`

Comment: Almost! The title now has the correct color but the X & Y **label** hasn't changed (either the color or the font size test). However, the tic-labels are changed by the above settings...

Comment: Let me guess you are using `CanvasAxisLabelRenderer`, on your labels, right? If so then in this case you require to repeat the options explicitly by setting the labelOptions, like so: `labelOptions: {textColor: '#eeccaa'}`

Comment: OK - I'm all new to this webapp stuff... are you referring to doing this in the CSS file? My IDE is complaining when I paste your suggestion in the various logical positions in the file. Perhaps you can eloborate a bit more for a newbie... and thanks! Definite progress!

Comment: Not in CSS. Add it in your graph options. PS: I am use to using the jqPlot directly so I have full control over it I am not sure how to set it in primefaces. Why don't you build a working sample on http://jsfiddle.net , so we can work together from there?

Comment: OK - it looks like PrimeFaces doesn't have all the hooks into jqPlot yet. Looks like some JS fiddling may be required...

Comment: I think so, and looking at [the primefaces tag doc about p:lineChart](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.2/p/lineChart.html) makes me think that they must use `CanvasAxisLabelRenderer` as they offer `xaxisAngle` and `yaxisAngle` which exactly this renderer allows to rotate, assuming this are angles for the labels, sadly doc doesn't say a thing about this.

Comment: For a proof that `CanvasAxisLabelRenderer` needs color of text to be specified in `labelOptions` see http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/ZbHsD/10/  Play with the example, e.g. comment out the `labelOptions` to see the color is lost.

Answer (score 0):

As Boro illustrates in his comments to his answer above, when using CanvasAxisLabelRenderer you need to use:

```
labelOptions: {textColor: '#eeccaa'}
```

in the xaxis or yaxis object block (same place you're referencing the labelRenderer):

```
yaxis:{
  label: 'Your Label'
  labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
  labelOptions: {textColor: '#eeccaa'},
  etc...
}
```

Just thought it would be good to highlight this rather than have it hide in a comment.

Thanks Boro!

Answer (score 0):

for my work this code

```
 axes: {
     xaxis: {
          borderColor: "#aa2626",
          tickOptions: {
             textColor: '#aa2626'
             }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

for me as I am working on an old projec, Primefaces 6.2, the code that worked for me is as follows:

```
  this.cfg.axesDefaults= {
                tickOptions: {
                    textColor: '#fff'
                }
            };
```

note: this part of the code is inside extender functions which is set as follows inside java bean:

```
model.setExtender("linechartExtender");
```

then add the javascript fnctions in the xhtml file:

```
  <h:outputScript >
        function linechartExtender() {
           
            this.cfg.axesDefaults= {
                tickOptions: {
                    textColor: '#fff'
                }
            };

            
        }
       linechartExtender();
    </h:outputScript>
```